# DRF- Django Rest Framework re_path query params - "Method \"GET\" not allowed."

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to GET on generics `RetrieveAPIView` class using the re_path method in urls.py file. After trying several combinations, I can only get the path method to work. I would like to get an endpoint something similar to `/file?id={some_uid}`.

So far I have the following:

- django: 3.0.6
- djangorestframework=3.11.0

**views.py:**

```
class UploadFileInfoView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = "id"
    queryset = Upload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UploadModelSerializer
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("file/", views.UploadFileView.as_view(), name="UploadFile"),
    # this works
    # path("file/<uuid:id>", views.UploadFileInfoView.as_view(), name="UploadFileInfo"), 
    # this does not
    re_path(r"^file/(?P<id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)", views.UploadFileInfoView.as_view(), name="UploadFileInfo"),
]
```

Have not used url method as the documentation says

> This function is an alias to `django.urls.re_path()`. It’s likely to be deprecated in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Query param is passed to the django views by default. So you don't need to handle it explicitly in the URL. In your case if you want `/file?id={some_uid}` , you should handle it in the view or overwrite the `get_queryset` method.

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
# ** your other urls **
    path(r"file", views.UploadFileInfoView.as_view(), name="UploadFileInfo"),
]
```

## views.py

```
class UploadFileInfoView(generics.ListAPIView):
    lookup_field = "id"
    queryset = Upload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UploadModelSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Upload.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('id'))
```

the above setup will work for `/file/?id=1234` and return `Upload.objects.get(id=1234)`. I have not tested this code but it should work and also you need to handle exception if the object is not present.

Comment: **Error: The `actions` argument must be provided when calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example `.as_view({'get': 'list'})`**

```router.register(r'summary_metrics', views.SummaryMetricsViewSet.as_view(), name='SummaryMetrics')```

This happened when I tried both in `router.register` and `urlpatterns`.